# Error.getStackTrace() in AS3 + AIR 3.5/3.6 returns no stacktrace on Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, stack-trace

I developed a project in Flashdevelop with AIR 3.4. I've upgraded (an external) Flex SDK folder to AIR 3.6 and am also in the application.xml file referring to 3.6 this way:

<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.6">

However, after deploying the APK, I still don't get any stacktraces from caught error events. Any idea what I've overlooked? 
I know that AIR 3.5 enabled stacktraces also in release mode, but all I am getting is "null". Oh, and I am compiling with captive runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded now the latest and greatest version of flashdevelop, made sure that flash develop's own version of flex is ALSO AIR 3.6 and now it seems to be working - I am getting valid stacktraces, as advertised in the update logs of AIR 3.5